# ansible - consistent tagging across roles

Tags: ansible

I'm working on an ansible playbook which controls the deployment and maintenance of our test env's. We have a database, java glassfish and activemq process and a nginx process. We have a standard directory structure with roles, and then common install, start, stop tasks within each role.

```
site.yml
roles
    database
        tasks
            main.yml
            install.yml
            start.yml
            stop.yml
    glassfish
        tasks
            main.yml
            install.yml
            start.yml
            stop.yml
    nginx
        tasks
            main.yml
            install.yml
            start.yml
            stop.yml
```

At the moment we also have a few extra root level playbooks

```
site.yml
database.yml
glassfish.yml
nginx.yml
start.yml
stop.yml
install.yml
roles
```

which we call directly. I want to get rid of these and have a single site.yml but I'm looking for a recommendation on how i should tag these various tasks. Is there a recommended tag naming convention which stackoverflowers have used?

Answer (score 1):

In general I tag my roles with the names of the role itself by having a `tasks/main.yml` like this:

```
- include: <rolename>.yml
  tags: <rolename>
```

Then all my roles share a common tag `bootstrap` which is applied to tasks which take care of one-time actions, for example creating directory structure, installing specific version of a rpm/yum/apt package and so on. So all things that would have the same outcome and never produce changes when ran a 2nd time. Application config is not part of this, as this is likely to change. This `bootstrap` tag normally is skipped to speed up plays and only is triggered when a new host is being played for the first time. This probably would be what you have in your `install.yml`.

For starting, stopping and restarting services I have a `<role>_<start/stop/restart>` tag when required. But this actually is rarely used as most services only ever are restarted when its configuration was changed and that is done with handlers.